# get dropdown Selected save value whilst editing a form

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown and upon editing the document I cannot get the dropdown value already saved to show up in the edit form. the dropdownEntitiesSettings is set for singleSelection only.  What am I doing wrong?

code

```
<label class="col-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold text-right">Entity *:</label>

          <div class="col-4">

            <ng-multiselect-dropdown
              [(ngModel)]="entitySelected"
              [data]="entities"
              [settings]="dropdownEntitiesSettings"
              name="entitySelected"
              #entityListCheck="ngModel"
              placeholder="Select...">
            </ng-multiselect-dropdown>

            <div *ngIf="docForm.submitted && entityListCheck.errors?.emptyField" class="text-danger"
                 [ngClass]="{'alert-border': entityListCheck.errors?.emptyField}">
              You must select an entity
            </div>

          </div>
```

Typescript

```
// get data of document in the case of edit
 getDocById(docId: number){
this.showeditspinner = true;
this.editingDoc = true;
this.showDocForm = true;
this.docId= docId;
this.docFormService.getdocInfoById(docId).subscribe(
  resp =>{
    console.log(resp);
   console.log(resp.city.province.name);
    console.log(resp.city.name);
    this.docId= resp.id;
    this.document.id = resp.id;
    this.document.name = resp.name;
    this.document.address = resp.address;
    this.document.entityId = resp.entityId;
    this.document.city.province.id = resp.city.province.name;
    this.document.postalCode = resp.postalCode;
    this.document.city = resp.city;
    this.document.phoneNumber = resp.phoneNumber;
    this.document.email = resp.email;
    this.doWorkCenter = false;
    }
```

Comment: can you add `entities` object here?
Ref:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

In ng-multiselect-dropdown value will be set based on your data field, and its type will be array.

Example :

```
entities = [{name: "name1",value: "value1"},
{name: "name2",value: "value2"},
{name: "name3",value: "value3"}];
```

then your entitySelected value should be like

```
entitySelected = [{name: "name2",value: "value2"}];
```